# No slot of name "images" error when trying to open RDS file

Tags: r, seurat

I'm trying to open a file but it seems I'm running into an error.

Here's what I'm doing, in RStudio:

```
file <- readRDS("~/Downloads/file.rds")

View(file)
```

And then I get this error:

> Error in eval(call("@", object, slot)) :    no slot of name "images"
> for this object of class "Seurat"

The RDS file requires Seurat but I have that installed properly. I'm not sure how to interpret this error message. Thanks

Comment: Was it possibly made with a different version of Seurat? I wonder if the object structure may have changed (just a guess). Was there a gab between when you made the rds and when you opened it? Or does this happen with all objects you make with Seurat?

Comment: Now that you mention it, this was made with a different version of Seurat. If that is the problem, is there a simpler way to fix it other than uninstalling the current version Seurat and moving to an older one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try updating the seurat object:

pmbc.updated = UpdateSeuratObject(object = pmbc)